# Can it be optimized?

Tags: performance, query-performance

```
SELECT name, SUM(total) as total_expenditure FROM sale
    INNER JOIN client 
        ON sale.client_id = client.person_id
    INNER JOIN person 
        ON client.person_id = person.id
GROUP BY (sale.client_id)
HAVING total_expenditure = (
    SELECT MAX(total_buy) FROM(
        SELECT name, SUM(total) as total_buy FROM sale
            INNER JOIN client 
                ON sale.client_id = client.person_id
            INNER JOIN person 
                ON client.person_id = person.id
        GROUP BY client_id) x)
```

The objective is to get the client who spend more money on the stand.

Comment: Can you share a query plan, and provide the RDBMS that this accesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-write that using a window function, which should be faster, as the grouping only needs to be done once.

Your `group by` is also incorrect, you need to include `name` in the `group by`

You didn't specify your DBMS, so the is ANSI SQL.

```
select name, 
       total_expenditure
from (
  SELECT name, 
         SUM(total) as total_expenditure, 
         dense_rank() over (order by sum(total) desc) as rnk
  FROM sale
    JOIN client ON sale.client_id = client.person_id
    JOIN person ON client.person_id = person.id
  GROUP BY sale.client_id, sale.name --<< you need to include the name here to make this work correctly. 
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

Another possibility is to use `fetch first 1 rows only` if you don't care about multiple clients having the same maximum sale:

```
SELECT name, 
       SUM(total) as total_expenditure
FROM sale
  JOIN client ON sale.client_id = client.person_id
  JOIN person ON client.person_id = person.id
GROUP BY sale.client_id, sale.name
order by sum(total)
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

The second statement is not identical to the first one if there is more than one client with the same (maximum) total_expenditure. The first query will return *all* those clients, the second one only one of them.